# Update progressBar in Shiny while independent function is running

Tags: r, modal-dialog, shiny, progress-bar

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44043475/adjust-size-of-shiny-progress-bar-and-center-it).

Well, I have a `progressBar` in a modal, and I can update the progress using a for. Now I need to increment the `progressBar` while a function is executed. I know that I can run the `progressBar` update whenever I want, but I need the progress bar to increment only while a function is executed.

I tried this, but it shows the `progressBar` updated at 100 and if the function execution is heavy it looks like the page is frozen, and also shows the  default `progressDialog`.

UI:

```
tags$script("Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('launch-modal', function(d) {$('#' + d).modal().focus();})"),
tags$script("Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('remove-modal', function(d) {$('#' + d).modal('hide');})"),
tags$div(
  id = "my-modal",
  class="modal fade", tabindex="-1", `data-backdrop`="static", `data-keyboard`="false",
  tags$div(
    class="modal-dialog",
    tags$div(
      class = "modal-content",
      tags$div(class="modal-header", tags$h4(class="modal-title", "Running...")),
      tags$div(
        class="modal-body",
        shinyWidgets::progressBar(id = "pb", value = 0, display_pct = TRUE)
      )
    )
  )
```

Server:

```
shinyWidgets::updateProgressBar(session = session, id = "pb", value = 0) # reinitialize to 0 if you run the calculation several times
  session$sendCustomMessage(type = 'launch-modal', "my-modal") # launch the modal
  withProgress({
    shinyWidgets::updateProgressBar(session = session, id = "pb", value = 99)
    heavyFunctionToExecute()
  })
  Sys.sleep(0.5)
  session$sendCustomMessage(type = 'remove-modal', "my-modal") # hide the modal programmatically
```

Comment: could you tell more about `heavyFunctionToExecute()`, e.g. can it be split up and executed within a for loop?

Comment: Well, the `heavyFunctionToExecute()` is the `gsva()` function for the bioconductor package `GSVA`. It can't be executed in a loop or something, it's like if I'm using a default function that I don't know how it works.

Comment: well then it is tricky to update the progress bar meanwhile. The function description reads as you couldnt split up the input and run it several times, so unless you dont wont to rewrite the function yourself and see if you can split it up somehow, i dont see a way to use it in a combination with the progress bar :/,...

Comment: Well don't worry, thanks for the help, I'll be looking for a solution :)

Comment: You can show a shiny notification, only dismiss it after external function finished. This should be better suited in this case since you don't have progress information anyway.